Effective trace algorithm created 3 traps as response to 2 exceptions
I ran RISCV effective trace encoder python script with the following inputs:
0,0,0,0,0x80000104,4,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0x80000108,4,0,0,0,0,0
10,0,0,0,0x8000010C,4,0,0,0,0,0
1,6,0xEE,0,0x8000222,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,0,0,0,0x800001b0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0x800001e0,4,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0x800001e4,4,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0x800001e8,4,0,0,0,0,0

and got the following outputs:
format=SYNC, subformat=SUPPORT, ienable=1, encoder_mode=0, ioptions=23, qual_status=0, denable=0, dloss=0, doptions=0 Payload[1f 17]
next=80000154
next=80000104 curr=80000154
format=SYNC, subformat=START, address=80000154, branch=1, context=0, privilege=0, time=0, Reason[first_qualified] Payload[13 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 aa 00 00 40]
next=80000108 curr=80000104 prev=80000154
format=ADDR, address=80000104, irreport=0, irdepth=511, notify=0, updiscon=0, Reason[prev_updiscon] Payload[12 04 00 00 02 00 00 00 e0]
next=8000010c curr=80000108 prev=80000104
next=8000222 curr=8000010c prev=80000108
format=ADDR, address=8000010c, irreport=0, irdepth=511, notify=0, updiscon=0, Reason[next_exc_only] Payload[32 04 00 00 02 00 00 00 e0]
next=800001b0 curr=8000222 prev=8000010c
format=SYNC, subformat=TRAP, address=8000222, branch=1, context=0, ecause=6, interrupt=0, privilege=0, time=0, thaddr=0, tval=ee, Reason[prev_updiscon, curr_exc_only] Payload[17 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 83 88 00 00 02 00 00 00 80 3b]
next=800001e0 curr=800001b0 prev=8000222
format=SYNC, subformat=TRAP, address=800001b0, branch=1, context=0, ecause=6, interrupt=0, privilege=0, time=0, thaddr=0, tval=ee, Reason[prev_exception, curr_exc_only] Payload[17 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 6c 00 00 20 00 00 00 80 3b]
next=800001e4 curr=800001e0 prev=800001b0
format=SYNC, subformat=TRAP, address=800001e0, branch=1, context=0, ecause=0, interrupt=1, privilege=0, time=0, thaddr=1, Reason[prev_exception] Payload[17 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 78 00 00 20]
next=800001e8 curr=800001e4 prev=800001e0
format=ADDR, address=800001e8, irreport=0, irdepth=511, notify=0, updiscon=0 Payload[a2 07 00 00 02 00 00 00 e0]
format=SYNC, subformat=SUPPORT, ienable=0, encoder_mode=0, ioptions=23, qual_status=1, denable=0, dloss=0, doptions=0 Payload[4f 17]

as you can see 3 TRAP packets are generated as response to uninferred jump and 2 exception events. I expected 2 TRAPs and SYNC_START instead. What I miss here?
